# SqlAlchemy: case statement (case - if - then -else)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a `case` statement with SqlAlchemy, e.g. the [postgresql version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)

Maybe literal SQL is the way to go if there is no easy way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CASE WHEN with ORM (SQLalchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258770/case-when-with-orm-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out the documentation about the case statement here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case

Comment: Thanks! I had done a google site search for 'case' for sqlalchemy.org, but it is a much too common word. Just noticed that the search on the sqlalchemy site itself brings that page up first!

Comment: Please provide more than a link in your answer.

Answer (score 18):

**Reference from the Official [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) of SQLAlchemy**

> ```
> from sqlalchemy import case, literal_column
>
> case(
>     [
>         (
>             orderline.c.qty > 100,
>             literal_column("'greaterthan100'")
>         ),
>         (
>             orderline.c.qty > 10,
>             literal_column("'greaterthan10'")
>         )
>     ],
>     else_=literal_column("'lessthan10'")
> )
> ```
>
> The above will render the given constants without using bound
>   parameters for the result values (but still for the comparison
>   values), as in:
>
> ```
> CASE
>     WHEN (orderline.qty > 100) THEN 'greaterthan100'
>     WHEN (orderline.qty > 10) THEN 'greaterthan10'
>     ELSE 'lessthan10'
> END
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In my case solution provided by Anand Tripathi disn't worked 100% but that helps. So, I have updated the code to:

```
   from sqlalchemy import case, literal_column
   case(
       (
           orderline.c.qty > 100,
           literal_column("'greaterthan100'")
       ),
       (
           orderline.c.qty > 10,
           literal_column("'greaterthan10'")
       ),
       else_=literal_column("'lessthan10'")
    )
```