# How would I do this query with a case statement in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, and I need to implement a case statement in the query as follows:

```
select j.id, j.record_count, j.ev_job_id, j.created_at, j.csv, t.name,
case
  when j.status = 0 then 'Pending'
  when j.status = 1 then 'Complete'
end status
from job_status j
inner join list_types t on (j.list_type_id = t.id)
order by j.id desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy documentation explains their case statement implementation here:

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case

Or you might find this other SO question helpful:

- [CASE WHEN with ORM (SQLalchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258770/case-when-with-orm-sqlalchemy)

Comment: I ultimately had to implement this logic in my view. The case statement changes the data type from integer to string, breaking the ORM mapping.

Comment: You could always cast it back to int, but yeah, that's not a good thing. You might want to ask on the SQLAlchemy list about that and/or submit a bug ticket.

Comment: the link to sqlalchemy documentation is broken

Comment: Good catch. Fixed